# load external css file into haml

Tags: css, sinatra, haml

I'm using haml and sinatra

When the css is in the .haml file, the styling works.
When I use %link, the styling is not seen

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css")
```

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on the answer by looking at some sinatra apps on github.
I created a directory called public (same level as the views directory) and placed the styles.css file in that directory.